# Easiest Node.js/Express authorization

Tags: node.js, express, session, jwt

I'm creating API for our frontend and I have trouble finding easiest solution for basic Node.js/Express authorization needs. I already have authentication in place, but I want to secure specific API routes.

> Example case:
>   user can only fetch (and edit) it's own profile so he can't fetch someone else's just providing email address

I've read about sessions and I've read about JWT. Not really sure which way to go - I don't need anything fancy, just something that will protect users data from being fetched by unauthorized users.

I'm using MariaDB and local authentication strategy (email/password).

Answer (score 1):

If you have local authentication strategy already implemented, I'll add JWT for the API resources you want to protect. It's quite easy with passport libraries.

With JWT you can get the user that is sending the request and make all the security checks you need.

Comment: how about logging out? Will deleting token do the job or there is more to it?

Comment: JWT tokens are self content, and it's recomended they have an expire date included, so after it expires, token can't be used again. If you put an expire date not very long, it's enough to control that. You can complement a very short expire time with a refresh token.

Comment: I also found this article: https://medium.com/devgorilla/how-to-log-out-when-using-jwt-a8c7823e8a6 and that's why I'm struggling because token seems to be less hassle than sessions, but also a little bit less control. On the other hand - big services are somehow using these...

Comment: I've been using it for a long time and I recomend to use it better than sessions. You can add some control with the refresh token and adjusting times. Take a look a this article too: https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-node-js

Comment: Very nice article! I think the best one I read yet. So you don't actually implement sign out - users don't mind? And what expiry time would be considered safe? Also, I've also read about blacklisting - so for control token shouldn't be as self-contained?

Comment: I wrote that article,  so thanks :). The way we usually implement log out was delegating in the client the responsability to remove the token. At the momento you don't have the token, it's the same that be logged out.
We usually  use a very short expiry, and the clients have to implement auto-refresht token, so every time the token expires, client refresh the token automatically and transparently for the user. With this you could ban an user not allowing it authenticate again, and cancelling its refresh token.